# How do I set a label on a propagator using tikz-feynhand?

Tags: pdftex, latexmk, tikz-feynman

I'm trying to draw a Feynman diagram using the [tikz-feynhand](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.00689.pdf) package, but I'm having trouble setting labels on the lines it draws.
The following works fine to draw the lines with no labels:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynhand} % for feynman diagrams
% \usetikzlibrary{graphs,positioning} % for propagator labels

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynhand}
\vertex (u1) at (-1, 0);
\vertex (u2) at (1, 0);
\propag [fermion] (u1) to (u2);
\end{feynhand}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: propagator without label]

But when I try to specify the `edge label` option with `\propag [fermion, edge label=$u$] (u1) to (u2);`, I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfkeys@code ...odes \expandafter {\tikz@tonodes
                                                  #1}
l.19 \propag [fermion, edge label=$u$]
                                          (u1) to (u2);
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I'm compiling on Windows 10 using `latexmk`, which itself runs `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! The `edge label` has to be passed to `to`, and not to `\propag`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynhand} % for feynman diagrams
% \usetikzlibrary{graphs,positioning} % for propagator labels

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynhand}
\vertex (u1) at (-1, 0);
\vertex (u2) at (1, 0);
\propag [fermion] (u1) to[edge label=$u$] (u2);
\end{feynhand}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect, thank you very much!
I'll mark this as the accepted answer once enough time has passed to do so.